# Bash script to list all devices of PCI Bridge type

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script that lists names of all PCI Bridge devices on a computer, but I have no idea how to do it. 
I am pretty sure that I have to use lspci command, but I dont know if there is a parameter for it to list devices by type. My main problem is that I cant access my linux computer so I cant experiment with it, but:

I was thinking it could be something along the lines of:

```
function() {
 find= ???
 devices = $(lspci)  #not sure what to put here
 for i in ${!devices[*]}
 do
    device=($(${devices[$i]}))
    if  [! grep $find $device]; then
              echo $device

            fi
 done
}
```

Comment: that works on my machine: http://pastebin.com/wa9G69XN. i guess you can get that 00:1c by grepping the full `lspci` output for some magic words.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to browse the /sys file system. You can use `for`-loops, or the `find` command to do so.

- `/sys/bus/pci/devices` lists all devices as "directories" (or actually, links to the actual directory)
- Each directory contains information about that device, including its vendorId and productID, ...

Answer (score 0):

lspci has a -PP option, You can do some bash/awk around it to get full verbose listing

```
lspci -PP
```